# How to match my string? Do I need negative lookbehind?

Tags: python, regex

Let's assume we have the following string:

`This thing costs $5000.`

I'm trying to match up $5000 with negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!([:;]))\$?([0-9]+)
```

So that it doesn't find a match if it has ";" or ':' behind $5000, eg. ;$5000 or ;5000.

**First string:**

`This thing costs $5000`
or
`5000`

**Desired output:**

`$5000`
or
`5000`

**Second string:**

`This thing costs ;$5000`
or
`;5000`

**Desired output:**

`None`

Comment: To be clear, could you put your code including the examples you want to not match? For reference see [mre].

Comment: @anubhava Please don't answer questions in the comments. Anyway, that doesn't work properly. For `This thing costs ;$5000`, it matches: `<re.Match object; span=(19, 23), match='5000'>`

Comment: Use `(?<![;:$])\$?\b([0-9]+)`

Comment: Why did you make the dollar sign optional? And why did you include `;5000` as a counter-example? Are you trying to match `This thing costs 5000` as well? And for that matter, why did you make the dollar sign *zero-or-more*? Are you really trying to match something like `This thing costs $$$5000`?

Comment: Do you *have* to use a negative lookbehind for a school project or something? If not, there are simpler methods to achieve the same result.

Comment: Both ;5000 and ;$5000 should return None. Anyway, @mousetail answer works correctly. I'd like to know how ```/b``` works in this example, though.

Comment: @BeRT2me, I'm just new to regular expression, so I'd appreciate if you shared simpler methods.

Comment: What should be match for `This thing costs 8000` ?

Comment: @anubhava, 8000

Comment: What about `This thing costs8000`? (aka, is the space significant?)

Comment: ```None``` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is great but there's a single flaw: you can match from the middle of the digits or from the `$` sign.

Add `\d` and `$` to the negative lookback and it'll work:

```
(?<![;:\d$])\$?([0-9]+)
```

Examples:

```
>>> re.findall("(?<![;:\d$])\$?([0-9]+)", "This thing costs ;$5000")
[]
>>> re.findall("(?<![;:\d$])\$?([0-9]+)", "This thing costs $5000")
['5000']
```

Keep in mind I do suggest matching the number instead of dealing with negative lookbacks like so:

```
re.findall(r"\s\$?([0-9]+)", "This thing costs ;$5000")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, matching what you *do* want rather than what you *don't* want is easier. As far as I can tell, what you're really looking for is an integer that optionally start with `$`. But, you still want to capture the `$` if it's there. The `;` and `:` are just red-herrings.

```
import re

values = ['This thing costs $5000.',  # $5000
          'This thing costs ;$5000.', # None
          'This thing costs 5000.',   # 5000
          'This thing costs ;5000.',  # None
          'This thing costs8000']     # None

pattern = r'.*\s(\$?\d+)'

for value in values:
    # If a match is made, we want group 1 from that match.
    if match := re.match(pattern, value):
        print(match.group(1))
    else:
        print(match)
```

Output:

```
$5000
None
5000
None
None
```

See https://regexr.com/6sqbs for an in-depth explanation of my pattern `.*\s(\$?\d+)`